# date not inserted in database of android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

in my insert activity date of birth is not inserted in mysql database all other other record are inserted but date of birth not inserted.
following is my code:
getDate Function

```
  private void getDate() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            et_dob.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);


        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

params

```
 Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put(KEY_NAME,et_first_name.getText().toString());
            params.put(KEY_MIDDLE_NAME,et_middle_name.getText().toString());
            params.put(KEY_LAST_NAME,et_last_name.getText().toString());
            params.put(KEY_DOB,et_dob.getText().toString());
           // Log.d("mytag", "dob" + et_dob.getText().toString());
            params.put(KEY_CITY,et_city.getText().toString());
            params.put(KEY_GENDER,gender);
            params.put(KEY_STATE,et_state.getText().toString());
            return params;
```

onCreate

```
  et_first_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_first_name);
    et_middle_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_middle_name);
    et_last_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_last_name);
    et_dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_dob);
    et_state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_state);
    et_city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_city);
    rdb_1= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_male);
    rdb_2= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd_female);
```

xml for date

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:hint="Choose Date"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/et_dob"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etTime"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etTime" />
```

insert.php

```
if (isset($_POST['user_first_name'])&&($_POST['user_middle_name'])&&($_POST['user_last_name']) && ($_POST['user_date_of_birth'])&&($_POST['user_gender'])&& ($_POST['user_state'])&&($_POST['user_city'])){
```

extract($_POST);

```
$string_query="INSERT INTO `tbl_user` 
               (`user_first_name`,`user_middle_name`,`user_last_name`,`user_date_of_birth`,`user_gender`,`user_state`,`user_city`)
               VALUES 
               ('$user_first_name','$user_middle_name','$user_last_name','$user_date_of_birth','$user_gender','$user_state','$user_city')";
```

when i try to insert date `0000-00-00` this is inserted in database 
any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Any exception you are getting here?

Comment: no exception here

Comment: Check if the dateformat is matching

Answer (score 0):

Try using below mysql query to insert date ...

```
$string_query="INSERT INTO `tbl_user` 
           (`user_first_name`,`user_middle_name`,`user_last_name`,`user_date_of_birth`,`user_gender`,`user_state`,`user_city`)
           VALUES 
           ('$user_first_name','$user_middle_name','$user_last_name', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user_date_of_birth)),'$user_gender','$user_state','$user_city')";
```